# Как правльно заполнить DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

На форме есть 2 *TextBox*, *Button* и *DataGridView*. В *DataGridView* один столбец *ComboBoxColumn*, строки определяются значением первого *TextBox*.

Как по нажатию на *ComboBox* заполнить его элементами (их количество определяется значением второго *TextBox*)?

**Обновление**
Программа для строительной фирмы. Из за того что некоторые помещения (например, коридор) имеют форму не прямоугольную, приходиться разбивать на прямоугольники чтобы посчитать площади.
В *DataGridView* названия строк это - стены (количество вводится из *TextBox1*). В *TextBox2* вводится количество прямоугольников (на которые разбиваю). Чтобы потом посчитать площадь в столбце *ComboBox*, я выбираю к какому прямоугольнику относится стена. Если способов миллион, то не могли бы вы мне подсказать хотя бы один. Я пытался сделать через цикл, но не вышло.

Comment: Одним из миллиона различных способов, зависит от организации вашей программы.

Comment: а как вы будете считать площадь для здания например с такой планировкой: http://kapluk.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Планировка-этажа-2.jpg? Тут есть и полукруги, и трапеции...

Comment: Попробуйте MVVM. Положите наборы в коллекцию, прибиндьтесь к текущему элементу. При нажатии на кнопку отправляйте команду в VM, которая переключит текущий элемент.

Comment: @Norritt На счет подобных помещений есть отдельные задумки, но опять же для их реализации необходимо решить данную описанную проблему.    Как мне по нажатию кнопки в гриде ComboBox заполнялся элементами вроде "Помещение 1.....Помещение n"

Comment: Покажите предполагаемое содержимое текстбоксов. Только не пишите это в комментарии, отредактируйте сообщение.

Comment: @ГеоргийЛанец, грид - это Grid или DataGridView?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что делать со вторым `TextBox`. 
Вот например в результате выполнения этого кода:

```
int number = 0, t = 0;
try
{
    number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally 
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column", "Количество прямоугольников");
    while (number > 0)
    {
        t++;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Помещение " + t, textBox2.Text);
        number--;
    }
}
```

Мы получим такое окно:
[image: Результат]

Comment: Суть вот в чем: 1 textbox отвечает за количество стен, 2 textbox отвечает за количество помещений. В колонке(datagridviewcomboboxcolumn) количество элементов должно соответствовать значению 2го textbox. В 1 колонке datagridview у меня выводятся стены. Как раз таки из combobox'ов я делаю привязку стены к помещению